# how to compare field values of map in a for loop

Tags: apex, trigger, map

I have 2 objects I need to compare if same field record is not present in both object create record of one how to compare between map's sobject field and the list in for loop condition. below is the code snip I am trying to implement.

```
if(conGroup.SalesConnect__Contact__c!=mapJunc.contains(mapJunc.contact__c) && conGroup.SalesConnect__Group_Name__c!=mapJunc.contains(mapJunc.group_name__c))

public static void afterInsert(List<SalesConnect__Contact_Team__c> triggerNew){
    list<Teams_Junction_Object__c> insertObj = new list<Teams_Junction_Object__c>();

    map<id,Teams_Junction_Object__c> mapJunc = new map<id,Teams_Junction_Object__c>();

    for(Teams_Junction_Object__c juncObj:[select id,name,contact__c,group__c,group_name__c from Teams_Junction_Object__c]){
        if(mapJunc.containsKey(juncObj.id){
            mapJunc.get(juncObj.id).add(juncObj);
        }
        else{
            mapJunc.put(juncObj.id,juncObj);
        }
    }

    for(SalesConnect__Contact_Team__c conGroup: triggerNew){
        **if(conGroup.SalesConnect__Contact__c!=mapJunc.contains(mapJunc.contact__c) && conGroup.SalesConnect__Group_Name__c!=mapJunc.contains(mapJunc.group_name__c)){**
        Teams_Junction_Object__c newObj = new Teams_Junction_Object__c();
        newObj.Contact__c = conGroup.SalesConnect__Contact__c;
        newObj.Group__c = ;
        insertObj.add(newObj);
    }
}
insert insertObj;
```

Comment: You can update your question rather than put the detail in comments.

Answer (score -1):

We just need to change the map structure and the if condition a bit

1. Map to contain the values to compare
2. 'if condition' to check the values fetched from map
3. The context of whether both contact and group we compare belong to same record or not is achieved by comparing the IDs mapped to the values compared

```
        public static void afterInsert(List<SalesConnect__Contact_Team__c> triggerNew){
        list<Teams_Junction_Object__c> insertObj = new list<Teams_Junction_Object__c>();
    
        map<String, Id> mapContact = new map<String, Id>();
        map<String, Id> mapGroup = new map<String, Id>();
    
        for(Teams_Junction_Object__c juncObj:[select id,name,contact__c,group__c,group_name__c from Teams_Junction_Object__c]){
            mapContact.put(juncObj.contact__c, juncObj.Id);
            mapGroup.put(juncObj.group__c, juncObj.Id);
        }
    
        for(SalesConnect__Contact_Team__c conGroup: triggerNew){
            if(!(mapContact.containsKey(conGroup.SalesConnect__Contact__c) //checking if contact is already present  
    && mapGroup.containsKey(conGroup.SalesConnect__Group_Name__c) //checking if group is already present 
    && (mapContact.get(conGroup.SalesConnect__Contact__c) == mapGroup.containsKey(conGroup.SalesConnect__Group_Name__c)))){ //in case both are present, this line checks if both belongs to the same record by comparing the IDs    
            Teams_Junction_Object__c newObj = new Teams_Junction_Object__c();
            newObj.Contact__c = conGroup.SalesConnect__Contact__c;
            newObj.Group__c = conGroup.SalesConnect__Group_Name__c;
            insertObj.add(newObj);
    }
    }
    insert insertObj;
    }
```

Comment: Please add more of a description of what you changed.

Comment: @JPM Thanks for your reply but I need to compare if contact and group record is not in the junction object we will create a record in team junction object so I need to check not contains and both not equal in same record can you please suggest right condition for not contain

Comment: Updated the answer for not condition, Kindly check

Comment: @AdrianLarson thanks for notifying